# SQL Server Reporting Services: Which dataset corresponds with table/textbox?

Tags: sql-server, dataset, reporting, ssrs-2012

My predecessor built a report for a client, which has several tables and about 20 datasets. Several of the queries return the same field names.

Is there a way to click on a table, row group, or item in a report and find what dataset it's linked to? I don't see it in the Properties box.

Comment: Look at the properties for the containing table/tablix/matrix. This will have a DatasetName property

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on an `<<Expr>>` in a cell for example, and choose Expression... it'll open the Expression dialog.
In this dialog you can see which Dataset is being used in the expression.

e.g.:

```
=First(Fields!MyField.Value, "MyDataSet")
```